# Accessing char array from a class

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am learning C++ by game hacking a game named 'Assault Cube'. I generated this class using ReClass.NET

```
class playerObj
{
public:
    char pad_0000[4]; //0x0000
    Vector3 Angles; //0x0004
    float velocityForward; //0x0010
    float velocitySide; //0x0014
    float velocityJump; //0x0018
    char pad_001C[4]; //0x001C
    int32_t N00000011; //0x0020
    char pad_0024[4]; //0x0024
    float N00000013; //0x0028
    float N00000014; //0x002C
    char pad_0030[4]; //0x0030
    Vector3 Position; //0x0034
    float X_mouse_axis; //0x0040
    float Y_mouse_axis; //0x0044
    char pad_0048[56]; //0x0048
    int32_t isMoving; //0x0080
    char pad_0084[116]; //0x0084
    int32_t health; //0x00F8
    char pad_00FC[4]; //0x00FC
    char pad_0104[287]; //0x0104
    int8_t N0000008F; //0x0223
    int8_t N000002AD; //0x0224
    char playerName[16]; //0x0225
    char pad_0235[1775]; //0x0235
}; //Size: 0x0924
```

Then I make a pointer to playerObj

```
playerObj* localPlayer = (playerObj*)*(uintptr_t*)(0x50F4F4);
```

And I can access health variable like this

```
int32_t GetYourHealth() {
    int32_t playerHealth = localPlayer->health;
    return playerHealth;
}
```

However, I am having a problem accessing the playerName. I tried to do it like that :

```
char GetYourName() {
    char* yourName = localPlayer->playerName;
    return *yourName;
}
```

But it's not showing anything. How can I access the playerName char array?
**EDIT :**
I've done it, here is how :

```
char GetYourName() {
    char* yourName = localPlayer->playerName;
    std::cout << "Your name is : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(localPlayer->playerName); i++) {
        if (yourName[i] != '\0') {
            std::cout << yourName[i];
        }
    }
    return *yourName;
}
```

Comment: `*yourName` is equal to `*(yourName + 0)` which is equal to `yourName[0]`. It's a single character.

Comment: Your function signature is returning `char` but you are returning `char*` in your function.

Comment: Was is it your intention to return the first char only? That would've been easy: `char GetYourName() { return *localPlayer->playerName; }`. And, btw. why don't you bail out in the `else` of `if (yourName[i] != '\0')`. It will print the characters after 0-terminator as well (if not 0).

Comment: @Scheff I wanted to print the whole array and my code is doing it's job. In Assault Cube, player name is held in char array with the size of 16. If your player name is 'asd', it will appear as "...asd..........", so looping through it with for() and checking each character with if() leaves us with just 'asd', which is what I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using reclass generated classes is so you don't need to write these "Getter" functions, you can just access the member variables like any other class.

It's a null terminated string so all you have to do is:

```
std::cout << localPlayer->playerName << std::endl;
```